# iOS Application, Website, and Web Service - Should I use a framework?

Tags: php, mysql, ios, frameworks, laravel

I am developing an iOS application that will be communicating with a PHP/MySQL web service to send/receive data. My plan is to also have a website that has similar functionality to the iOS application and will also interact with the web service. Should I be using a framework to build this web service (I am thinking about Laravel)? Is it a good idea to have the web service separate from the website?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are building a native application and requires connection to your website or collecting info, I suggest you to build you own API to access the data from ios using json.

Comment: this should be a comment.

Comment: I need to have 50 reputation to make a comment.

Comment: there is your 50 reputation. enjoy.

Comment: My current plan is to write a JSON API using Laravel. However, I am new to web services and iOS applications and didn't know if there was a big downside to this.

Comment: Good to know about this framework, it's pretty simple and their documentation well organized, just got for it. Here's an example on android http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/13193/android-mysql-php-json-part-5-developing-the-android-application/.